# Google maps display polygon

Tags: google-maps, polygon

If i enter in [google maps](http://maps.google.com) a point with this format:40.77065496240177 22.69926567871095
it will display a point in the map.
How can i enter a polygon in the same way.
I ask this to check the validity of the polygon and to visualize.
Also if this is not visible in google maps is it more easier in google earth?

Comment: Are you creating a KML file or doing something different?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using one of the [Google Maps APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/), not maps.google.com.

Comment: @barrycarter.I'm checking the validity of the polygon

Comment: If you do decide to move to the Google Maps API look into encoded polygons. For simple polygons you dont get the full benefit of the encoding, but for large ones or many polygon overlays encoding them improves performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing that you just want to view and validate the polygon from within Google Maps, put the polygon into a simple KML file and then either:

- Put the file in a public place on a web server and put its URL into the Google Maps search box, or,
- Go to My Maps in Google Maps, create a new map, and import the KML file from your hard drive.

It's fairly easy to create a simple KML file with a polygon, here's some [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#polygons) with a simple example.

Comment: Note that KML objects can only be bound to limited event listeners. Mouseovers are not possible, for instance. In cases where you need more flexibility, use Google Maps' [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) object